# Fast Re-build C# app under Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Need to recompile my project (not large) under Windows 7 without setting up Visual Studio.
Is there any method to do that with minimum setup procedure. It's C# app, using System.Net.Sockets and some others from my other projects.

Should I set up whole VS to recompile just little code app? like batch build..

Or... is there any cloud/public servers with pre-installed different Operational Systems with Visual Studio, where I could upload my project and just re-build it under all platforms at once?

Comment: Why do you need to build on Windows 7?

Comment: cause I have that project compiled under XP, but client's "car" is 7-ed, I try to run it. Tried 32-x86, set XPSp3 compatability mode, under admin account, so, everything. I have 7 PC, but it'll be only this Monday, but i'd like to report its over today...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this batch script to compile my C# applications. Just pass in the solution name without the .sln extension

```
if exist %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 set MSBUILDPATH=%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5

if exist %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 set MSBUILDPATH=%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

set MSBUILD=%MSBUILDPATH%\msbuild.exe

%MSBUILD% /nologo /m /p:BuildInParallel=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" "%1.sln"
```

Comment: - Obviously this works for only the 3.5 and 4.0 frameworks, but can easily be adopted for 1.1 and 2.0 too.

Comment: good, what if it contains say embedded resources and subfolders with classes? Works as well?

Comment: thx, tried it, it duznt see references from references tree and configuration file. any idea how to fix it? duz it support Windows.Form kinda app?

Comment: guys, thank you all for ya help. all of ya replies are the answers. i've ran new Random().Next(5)+1, and the choice is 4-th answer... Tigran. I've set to each up mark. thank you all.

Comment: I don't know why it does not work for you. Maybe the paths need to be tweaked to be 100% relative to the project files themselves. (We use it to compile a solution with lots of projects and a few 3rd party libraries (https://github.com/tgiphil/MOSA-Project/blob/master/Source/Compile.bat).

Comment: Yes! Worked! Tried that long csc.exe - but msbuild much more better.
Thanks Phil.

Comment: Phil, thank you brother. You know how much time you saved for me? I'm happy I found the idea to batch build it... thought i need full VS to my client PC Win7.
I spent 3 days(!!!) understanding why it works under XP and duznt under W7. Tried nearly everything... it is WinXP compiled project... even "bugged" it with EventLogs shitlines. without success. it just duznt work... then i've got the idea to find that way - and your solution is just fitted me. from the first time it recompiled and built and right away worked... unbeleivable.. thanks a lot of lots!!!

Answer (score 1):

With the .net Framework installed, you can just use [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) or [csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx).

Comment: That would compile a single project, but don't you need msbuild (still free) to handle a solution?

Comment: @Chris Yes, for solutions, MSBuild, but from the OP it sounded like a little cs project to me.

Comment: guys, thank you all for ya help. all of ya replies are the answers. i've ran new Random().Next(5)+1, and the choice is 4-th answer... Tigran. I've set to each up mark. thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to use studio to compile without running the GUI?  If so, you have at lot less work to do.  Use devenv.exe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: guys, thank you all for ya help. all of ya replies are the answers. i've ran new Random().Next(5)+1, and the choice is 4-th answer... Tigran. I've set to each up mark. thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

csc /r:Reference1.DLL /r:Reference2.DLL /r:Reference3.DLL Main.cs...other cs

**/r**: pass refereences of your project 
after, pass **cs** files separated by *space*

**In order to run this in CMD o PowerShell, you may need to run **vcvars32.bat***, which you can copy from machine where you have VS installed, or just, before inserting command, set complete path to csc.exe*

Regards.

Comment: Tigran, is it possible to capture the batch build command that devenv formes for my project?

Comment: yes sure, if consider a fact that as you said your project/solution is simple enough, so you shouldn't to have complex (wierd) dependency tree. Just build one project after another, by adding necessary referencies of another projects DLLs (if any), which were build before, obviously.

Comment: Tigran, what if the references are .NET native, like System.Core, should I pass full path to each one?

Comment: guys, thank you all for ya help. all of ya replies are the answers. i've ran new Random().Next(5)+1, and the choice is 4-th answer... Tigran. I've set to each up mark. thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Build project on commandline with msbuild.exe (comes with the framework).

No need to use devenv (which is vs) or csc (which requires you to specify dependencies etc.)

Comment: Is it possible to capture the batch build command that devenv formes for my project?

Comment: thnx, duz it support Windows.Form apps?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, devenv should build exactly like msbuild does (I believe VS simply uses msbuild internally). Should build any .net proj/sln

Comment: so, devenv builds that batch build command for me, right? then how could i catch that command statement? jst hate to understand that set of options... not enough time, really.

Comment: What do you mean by "batch build command"? And what do you mean by "catch"?

Comment: well, when i press rebuild, the devenv runs msbuild right? and it's already has all the options. then can i get that statement somehow from devenv?

Comment: well, i found it in output win

Comment: guys, thank you all for ya help. all of ya replies are the answers. i've ran new Random().Next(5)+1, and the choice is 4-th answer... Tigran. I've set to each up mark. thank you all.